Highchart presents UTC time instead of local time - while configured to show local time
I have that highchart settings: (I literally did copy paste of the final object)
{
    "responsive": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "condition": {
                    "maxWidth": 500
                },
                "_id": "highcharts-j9kyewe-155"
            }
        ]
    },
    "chart": {
        "type": "area",
        "style": {
            "cursor": "pointer"
        },
        "zooming": {
            "type": "x"
        }
    },
    "time": {
        "useUTC": false
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "",
        "align": "left"
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "",
        "align": "left"
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "lineWidth": 1,
        "lineColor": "#d2d8db",
        "labels": {
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
                "fontWeight": "400",
                "fontSize": "0.75rem",
                "color": "#3f5c69"
            }
        },
        "type": "datetime"
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "labels": {
            "style": {
                "fontFamily": "Open Sans",
                "fontWeight": "400",
                "fontSize": "0.75rem",
                "color": "#3f5c69"
            }
        },
        "title": {
            "text": ""
        }
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "area": {
            "marker": {
                "radius": 2
            },
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "color": {
                "linearGradient": {
                    "x1": 0,
                    "y1": 0,
                    "x2": 0,
                    "y2": 1
                },
                "stops": [
                    [
                        0.5,
                        "#95AAB8"
                    ],
                    [
                        1,
                        "#F3F6F7"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "states": {
                "hover": {
                    "lineWidth": 1
                }
            },
            "threshold": null
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "data": [
                [
                    1704067200000,
                    50.75
                ],
                [
                    1704070800000,
                    57.79999923706055
                ],
                [
                    1704074400000,
                    41.55555725097656
                ],
                [
                    1704078000000,
                    44.14285659790039
                ],
                [
                    1704081600000,
                    59.55555725097656
                ],
                [
                    1704085200000,
                    46.92856979370117
                ],
                [
                    1704088800000,
                    60
                ],
                [
                    1704092400000,
                    70.55555725097656
                ],
                [
                    1704096000000,
                    58.3636360168457
                ],
                [
                    1704099600000,
                    52.42856979370117
                ],
                [
                    1704103200000,
                    61
                ],
                [
                    1704106800000,
                    78.9000015258789
                ],
                [
                    1704110400000,
                    71.0999984741211
                ],
                [
                    1704114000000,
                    38.099998474121094
                ],
                [
                    1704117600000,
                    61.70000076293945
                ],
                [
                    1704121200000,
                    50.5
                ],
                [
                    1704124800000,
                    52.83333206176758
                ],
                [
                    1704128400000,
                    44.46154022216797
                ],
                [
                    1704132000000,
                    52.09090805053711
                ],
                [
                    1704135600000,
                    52.83333206176758
                ],
                [
                    1704139200000,
                    34.66666793823242
                ],
                [
                    1704142800000,
                    60.75
                ],
                [
                    1704146400000,
                    64.80000305175781
                ],
                [
                    1704150000000,
                    46.20000076293945
                ]
            ],
            "lineColor": "#7E97A8",
            "name": "",
            "type": "area"
        }
    ],
    "exporting": {
        "enabled": false,
        "buttons": {
            "contextButton": {
                "enabled": false
            }`your text`
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "resolution": "Hour"
    }
}

**I suppose to see all the dates at local time, but I see on UTC why?**  I tried according to the documentation to add that to the settings:
time: {
useUTC: false
},

but I still saw UTC time

I tried to use :
time: { useUTC: false }
it did not work
what am I doing wrong? let me know how to fix it thank you

The timezone.useUTC option is currently deprecated, and it's recommended to use the time.timezone setting. You can set this property to undefined and it should fall back to the local browser time zone.
time: {
    timezone: undefined
}

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9kdb8er4/
API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/time.timezone
